# why are these dates and times adding vertical lines in the future on tradingview?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

i am trying to a add these dates and times on to a Tradingview chart - it appears that they are on the chart but not at correct times and dates, they are after May 24th, which is the future!

Any ideas or fixes would be very helpful!

```
//@version=4
study("Economic News Vertical Lines", shorttitle="Econ News", overlay=true)

// Define event times (PST, UTC-7)
event1 = timestamp("2023-05-01T00:00:00")
event2 = timestamp("2023-05-01T00:00:00")
event3 = timestamp("2023-05-01T00:00:00")
event4 = timestamp("2023-05-01T00:00:00")
event5 = timestamp("2023-05-01T06:30:00")
event6 = timestamp("2023-05-01T06:45:00")
event7 = timestamp("2023-05-01T07:00:00")
event8 = timestamp("2023-05-01T07:00:00")
event9 = timestamp("2023-05-01T07:00:00")
event10 = timestamp("2023-05-01T07:00:00")
event11 = timestamp("2023-05-01T16:01:00")
event12 = timestamp("2023-05-01T16:50:00")
event13 = timestamp("2023-05-01T21:30:00")
event14 = timestamp("2023-05-01T21:30:00")
event15 = timestamp("2023-05-01T23:00:00")
event16 = timestamp("2023-05-01T23:00:00")
event17 = timestamp("2023-05-02T00:00:00")
event18 = timestamp("2023-05-02T00:15:00")
event19 = timestamp("2023-05-02T00:30:00")
event20 = timestamp("2023-05-02T00:45:00")
event21 = timestamp("2023-05-02T00:50:00")
event22 = timestamp("2023-05-02T00:55:00")
event23 = timestamp("2023-05-02T01:00:00")
event24 = timestamp("2023-05-02T01:00:00")
event25 = timestamp("2023-05-02T01:30:00")
event26 = timestamp("2023-05-02T02:00:00")
event27 = timestamp("2023-05-02T02:00:00")
event28 = timestamp("2023-05-02T02:00:00")
event29 = timestamp("2023-05-02T04:20:00")
event30 = timestamp("2023-05-02T07:00:00")
event31 = timestamp("2023-05-02T07:00:00")
event32 = timestamp("2023-05-02T07:00:00")
event33 = timestamp("2023-05-02T07:53:00")
event34 = timestamp("2023-05-02T14:00:00")
event35 = timestamp("2023-05-02T15:45:00")
event36 = timestamp("2023-05-02T15:45:00")
event37 = timestamp("2023-05-02T18:00:00")
event38 = timestamp("2023-05-02T18:30:00")
event39 = timestamp("2023-05-02T21:55:00")
event40 = timestamp("2023-05-02T23:45:00")
event41 = timestamp("2023-05-03T01:00:00")
event42 = timestamp("2023-05-03T02:00:00")
event43 = timestamp("2023-05-03T05:15:00")
event44 = timestamp("2023-05-03T06:45:00")
event45 = timestamp("2023-05-03T07:00:00")
event46 = timestamp("2023-05-03T07:30:00")
event47 = timestamp("2023-05-03T11:00:00")
event48 = timestamp("2023-05-03T11:30:00")
event49 = timestamp("2023-05-03T15:45:00")
event50 = timestamp("2023-05-03T18:00:00")
event51 = timestamp("2023-05-03T18:00:00")
event52 = timestamp("2023-05-03T18:00:00")
event53 = timestamp("2023-05-03T18:30:00")
event54 = timestamp("2023-05-03T20:00:00")
event55 = timestamp("2023-05-03T20:30:00")
event56 = timestamp("2023-05-03T21:30:00")
event57 = timestamp("2023-05-03T23:45:00")
event58 = timestamp("2023-05-04T01:00:00")
event59 = timestamp("2023-05-04T02:00:00")
event60 = timestamp("2023-05-04T02:45:00")
event61 = timestamp("2023-05-04T03:00:00")
event62 = timestamp("2023-05-04T03:30:00")
event63 = timestamp("2023-05-04T04:00:00")
event64 = timestamp("2023-05-04T04:00:00")
event65 = timestamp("2023-05-04T05:15:00")
event66 = timestamp("2023-05-04T07:00:00")
event67 = timestamp("2023-05-04T07:30:00")
event68 = timestamp("2023-05-04T23:45:00")
event69 = timestamp("2023-05-05T01:00:00")
event70 = timestamp("2023-05-05T02:00:00")
event71 = timestamp("2023-05-05T02:45:00")
event72 = timestamp("2023-05-05T03:00:00")
event73 = timestamp("2023-05-05T03:30:00")
event74 = timestamp("2023-05-05T04:00:00")
event75 = timestamp("2023-05-05T05:15:00")
event76 = timestamp("2023-05-05T06:45:00")
event77 = timestamp("2023-05-05T07:00:00")
event78 = timestamp("2023-05-05T09:00:00")
event79 = timestamp("2023-05-05T09:55:00")
event80 = timestamp("2023-05-05T10:00:00")
event81 = timestamp("2023-05-05T10:00:00")
event82 = timestamp("2023-05-05T11:00:00")
event83 = timestamp("2023-05-05T13:30:00")
event84 = timestamp("2023-05-05T15:00:00")
event85 = timestamp("2023-05-05T18:00:00")
event86 = timestamp("2023-05-05T18:00:00")
event87 = timestamp("2023-05-05T18:00:00")
event88 = timestamp("2023-05-05T18:00:00")
event89 = timestamp("2023-05-05T21:30:00")
event90 = timestamp("2023-05-05T23:45:00")
event91 = timestamp("2023-05-06T00:00:00")
event92 = timestamp("2023-05-06T01:00:00")
event93 = timestamp("2023-05-06T06:00:00")
event94 = timestamp("2023-05-06T23:45:00")
event95 = timestamp("2023-05-07T00:00:00")
event96 = timestamp("2023-05-07T06:45:00")
event97 = timestamp("2023-05-07T09:01:00")
event98 = timestamp("2023-05-07T11:30:00")
event99 = timestamp("2023-05-08T00:00:00")
event100 = timestamp("2023-05-08T00:00:00")
event101 = timestamp("2023-05-08T00:00:00")
event102 = timestamp("2023-05-08T05:00:00")
event103 = timestamp("2023-05-08T05:00:00")
event104 = timestamp("2023-05-08T05:00:00")
event105 = timestamp("2023-05-08T07:00:00")
event106 = timestamp("2023-05-08T07:30:00")
event107 = timestamp("2023-05-08T08:30:00")
event108 = timestamp("2023-05-08T08:55:00")
event109 = timestamp("2023-05-08T23:45:00")
event110 = timestamp("2023-05-09T01:00:00")
event111 = timestamp("2023-05-09T02:00:00")
event112 = timestamp("2023-05-09T02:45:00")
event113 = timestamp("2023-05-09T03:00:00")
event114 = timestamp("2023-05-09T03:30:00")
event115 = timestamp("2023-05-09T04:00:00")
event116 = timestamp("2023-05-09T05:15:00")
event117 = timestamp("2023-05-09T07:00:00")
event118 = timestamp("2023-05-09T07:30:00")
event119 = timestamp("2023-05-09T23:45:00")
event120 = timestamp("2023-05-10T01:00:00")
event121 = timestamp("2023-05-10T02:00:00")
event122 = timestamp("2023-05-10T02:45:00")
event123 = timestamp("2023-05-10T03:00:00")
event124 = timestamp("2023-05-10T03:30:00")
event125 = timestamp("2023-05-10T04:00:00")
event126 = timestamp("2023-05-10T05:15:00")
event127 = timestamp("2023-05-10T06:45:00")
event128 = timestamp("2023-05-10T07:00:00")
event129 = timestamp("2023-05-10T09:00:00")
event130 = timestamp("2023-05-10T09:55:00")
event131 = timestamp("2023-05-10T10:00:00")
event132 = timestamp("2023-05-10T10:00:00")
event133 = timestamp("2023-05-10T11:00:00")
event134 = timestamp("2023-05-10T13:30:00")
event135 = timestamp("2023-05-10T15:00:00")
event136 = timestamp("2023-05-10T18:00:00")
event137 = timestamp("2023-05-10T18:00:00")
event138 = timestamp("2023-05-10T18:00:00")
event139 = timestamp("2023-05-10T18:00:00")
event140 = timestamp("2023-05-10T21:30:00")
event141 = timestamp("2023-05-10T23:45:00")
event142 = timestamp("2023-05-11T01:00:00")
event143 = timestamp("2023-05-11T02:00:00")
event144 = timestamp("2023-05-11T02:45:00")
event145 = timestamp("2023-05-11T03:00:00")
event146 = timestamp("2023-05-11T03:30:00")
event147 = timestamp("2023-05-11T04:00:00")
event148 = timestamp("2023-05-11T05:15:00")
event149 = timestamp("2023-05-11T07:00:00")
event150 = timestamp("2023-05-11T07:30:00")
event151 = timestamp("2023-05-11T23:45:00")
event152 = timestamp("2023-05-12T01:00:00")
event153 = timestamp("2023-05-12T02:00:00")
event154 = timestamp("2023-05-12T02:45:00")
event155 = timestamp("2023-05-12T03:00:00")
event156 = timestamp("2023-05-12T03:30:00")
event157 = timestamp("2023-05-12T04:00:00")
event158 = timestamp("2023-05-12T05:15:00")
event159 = timestamp("2023-05-12T06:45:00")
event160 = timestamp("2023-05-12T07:00:00")
event161 = timestamp("2023-05-12T09:00:00")
event162 = timestamp("2023-05-12T09:55:00")
event163 = timestamp("2023-05-12T10:00:00")
event164 = timestamp("2023-05-12T10:00:00")
event165 = timestamp("2023-05-12T11:00:00")
event166 = timestamp("2023-05-12T13:30:00")
event167 = timestamp("2023-05-12T15:00:00")
event168 = timestamp("2023-05-12T18:00:00")
event169 = timestamp("2023-05-12T18:00:00")
event170 = timestamp("2023-05-12T18:00:00")
event171 = timestamp("2023-05-12T18:00:00")
event172 = timestamp("2023-05-12T21:30:00")
event173 = timestamp("2023-05-12T23:45:00")
event174 = timestamp("2023-05-13T00:00:00")
event175 = timestamp("2023-05-13T01:00:00")
event176 = timestamp("2023-05-13T06:00:00")
event177 = timestamp("2023-05-13T23:45:00")
event178 = timestamp("2023-05-14T00:00:00")
event179 = timestamp("2023-05-14T06:45:00")
event180 = timestamp("2023-05-14T09:01:00")
event181 = timestamp("2023-05-14T11:30:00")
event182 = timestamp("2023-05-15T00:00:00")
event183 = timestamp("2023-05-15T00:00:00")
event184 = timestamp("2023-05-15T00:00:00")
event185 = timestamp("2023-05-15T05:00:00")
event186 = timestamp("2023-05-15T05:00:00")
event187 = timestamp("2023-05-15T07:00:00")
event188 = timestamp("2023-05-15T07:30:00")
event189 = timestamp("2023-05-15T08:30:00")
event190 = timestamp("2023-05-15T08:55:00")
event191 = timestamp("2023-05-15T23:45:00")
event192 = timestamp("2023-05-16T01:00:00")
event193 = timestamp("2023-05-16T02:00:00")
event194 = timestamp("2023-05-16T02:45:00")
event195 = timestamp("2023-05-16T03:00:00")
event196 = timestamp("2023-05-16T03:30:00")
event197 = timestamp("2023-05-16T04:00:00")
event198 = timestamp("2023-05-16T05:15:00")
event199 = timestamp("2023-05-16T07:00:00")
event200 = timestamp("2023-05-16T07:30:00")
event201 = timestamp("2023-05-16T23:45:00")
event202 = timestamp("2023-05-17T01:00:00")
event203 = timestamp("2023-05-17T02:00:00")
event204 = timestamp("2023-05-17T02:45:00")
event205 = timestamp("2023-05-17T03:00:00")
event206 = timestamp("2023-05-17T03:30:00")
event207 = timestamp("2023-05-17T04:00:00")
event208 = timestamp("2023-05-17T05:15:00")
event209 = timestamp("2023-05-17T06:45:00")
event210 = timestamp("2023-05-17T07:00:00")
event211 = timestamp("2023-05-17T09:00:00")
event212 = timestamp("2023-05-17T09:55:00")
event213 = timestamp("2023-05-17T10:00:00")
event214 = timestamp("2023-05-17T10:00:00")
event215 = timestamp("2023-05-17T11:00:00")
event216 = timestamp("2023-05-17T13:30:00")
event217 = timestamp("2023-05-17T15:00:00")
event218 = timestamp("2023-05-17T18:00:00")
event219 = timestamp("2023-05-17T18:00:00")
event220 = timestamp("2023-05-17T18:00:00")
event221 = timestamp("2023-05-17T18:00:00")
event222 = timestamp("2023-05-17T21:30:00")
event223 = timestamp("2023-05-17T23:45:00")
event224 = timestamp("2023-05-18T01:00:00")

// Function to draw vertical lines
draw_vertical_line(time_event, color) =>
    var line p = line.new(x1=time_event, y1=na, x2=time_event, y2=na, width=1, color=color, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, style=line.style_dotted)
    line.set_xy1(p, x=time_event, y=lowest(low, 500))
    line.set_xy2(p, x=time_event, y=highest(high, 500))



// Draw vertical lines for all events
draw_vertical_line(event1, color.purple) // All Day: CAD Bank Holiday
draw_vertical_line(event2, color.green) // Mon May 1  All Day: GBP
draw_vertical_line(event3, color.green) // Mon May 1  All Day: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event4, color.green) // Mon May 1  All Day: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event5, color.green) // Mon May 1  All Day: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event6, color.blue) // Mon May 1  6:30am: CAD
draw_vertical_line(event7, color.blue) // Mon May 1  6:45am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event8, color.blue) // Mon May 1  7:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event9, color.blue) // Mon May 1  7:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event10, color.blue) // Mon May 1  7:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event11, color.green) // Mon May 1  4:01pm: GBP
draw_vertical_line(event12, color.yellow) // Mon May 1  4:50pm: JPY
draw_vertical_line(event13, color.orange) // Mon May 1  9:30pm: AUD
draw_vertical_line(event14, color.orange) // Mon May 1  9:30pm: AUD
draw_vertical_line(event15, color.green) // Mon May 1  11:00pm: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event16, color.green) // Mon May 1  11:00pm: GBP
draw_vertical_line(event17, color.purple) // Tue May 2  12:00am: CHF
draw_vertical_line(event18, color.green) // Tue May 2  12:15am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event19, color.purple) // Tue May 2  12:30am: CHF
draw_vertical_line(event20, color.green) // Tue May 2  12:45am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event21, color.green) // Tue May 2  12:50am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event22, color.green) // Tue May 2  12:55am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event23, color.green) // Tue May 2  1:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event24, color.green) // Tue May 2  1:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event25, color.green) // Tue May 2  1:30am: GBP
draw_vertical_line(event26, color.green) // Tue May 2  2:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event27, color.green) // Tue May 2  2:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event28, color.green) // Tue May 2  2:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event29, color.orange) // Tue May 2  4:20am: AUD
draw_vertical_line(event30, color.blue) // Tue May 2  7:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event31, color.blue) // Tue May 2  7:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event32, color.blue) // Tue May 2  7:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event33, color.green) // Tue May 2  7:53am: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event34, color.green) // Tue May 2  2:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event35, color.green) // Tue May 2  3:45pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event36, color.green) // Tue May 2  3:45pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event37, color.green) // Tue May 2  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event38, color.orange) // Tue May 2  6:30pm: AUD
draw_vertical_line(event39, color.orange) // Tue May 2  9:55pm: AUD
draw_vertical_line(event40, color.green) // Tue May 2  11:45pm: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event41, color.green) // Wed May 3  1:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event42, color.green) // Wed May 3  2:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event43, color.blue) // Wed May 3  5:15am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event44, color.blue) // Wed May 3  6:45am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event45, color.blue) // Wed May 3  7:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event46, color.blue) // Wed May 3  7:30am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event47, color.blue) // Wed May 3  11:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event48, color.blue) // Wed May 3  11:30am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event49, color.green) // Wed May 3  3:45pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event50, color.green) // Wed May 3  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event51, color.green) // Wed May 3  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event52, color.green) // Wed May 3  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event53, color.orange) // Wed May 3  6:30pm: AUD
draw_vertical_line(event54, color.orange) // Wed May 3  8:00pm: AUD
draw_vertical_line(event55, color.orange) // Wed May 3  8:30pm: AUD
draw_vertical_line(event56, color.orange) // Wed May 3  9:30pm: AUD
draw_vertical_line(event57, color.green) // Wed May 3  11:45pm: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event58, color.green) // Thu May 4  1:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event59, color.green) // Thu May 4  2:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event60, color.purple) // Thu May 4  2:45am: CHF
draw_vertical_line(event61, color.green) // Thu May 4  3:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event62, color.green) // Thu May 4  3:30am: GBP
draw_vertical_line(event63, color.green) // Thu May 4  4:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event64, color.green) // Thu May 4  4:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event65, color.blue) // Thu May 4  5:15am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event66, color.blue) // Thu May 4  7:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event67, color.blue) // Thu May 4  7:30am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event68, color.green) // Thu May 4  11:45pm: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event69, color.green) // Fri May 5  1:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event70, color.green) // Fri May 5  2:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event71, color.purple) // Fri May 5  2:45am: CHF
draw_vertical_line(event72, color.green) // Fri May 5  3:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event73, color.green) // Fri May 5  3:30am: GBP
draw_vertical_line(event74, color.green) // Fri May 5  4:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event75, color.blue) // Fri May 5  5:15am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event76, color.blue) // Fri May 5  6:45am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event77, color.blue) // Fri May 5  7:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event78, color.blue) // Fri May 5  9:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event79, color.blue) // Fri May 5  9:55am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event80, color.blue) // Fri May 5  10:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event81, color.blue) // Fri May 5  10:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event82, color.blue) // Fri May 5  11:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event83, color.orange) // Fri May 5  1:30pm: CAD
draw_vertical_line(event84, color.orange) // Fri May 5  3:00pm: CAD
draw_vertical_line(event85, color.green) // Fri May 5  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event86, color.green) // Fri May 5  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event87, color.green) // Fri May 5  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event88, color.green) // Fri May 5  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event89, color.orange) // Fri May 5  9:30pm: AUD
draw_vertical_line(event90, color.green) // Fri May 5  11:45pm: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event91, color.purple) // Sat May 6  All Day: CNY
draw_vertical_line(event92, color.green) // Sat May 6  1:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event93, color.green) // Sat May 6  6:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event94, color.green) // Sat May 6  11:45pm: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event95, color.purple) // Sun May 7  All Day: CNY
draw_vertical_line(event96, color.blue) // Sun May 7  6:45pm: USD
draw_vertical_line(event97, color.green) // Sun May 7  9:01pm: GBP
draw_vertical_line(event98, color.orange) // Sun May 7  11:30pm: AUD
draw_vertical_line(event99, color.green) // Mon May 8  All Day: GBP
draw_vertical_line(event100, color.green) // Mon May 8  All Day: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event101, color.green) // Mon May 8  All Day: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event102, color.blue) // Mon May 8  5:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event103, color.blue) // Mon May 8  5:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event104, color.blue) // Mon May 8  5:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event105, color.blue) // Mon May 8  7:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event106, color.blue) // Mon May 8  7:30am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event107, color.blue) // Mon May 8  8:30am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event108, color.blue) // Mon May 8  8:55am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event109, color.green) // Mon May 8  11:45pm: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event110, color.green) // Tue May 9  1:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event111, color.green) // Tue May 9  2:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event112, color.purple) // Tue May 9  2:45am: CHF
draw_vertical_line(event113, color.green) // Tue May 9  3:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event114, color.green) // Tue May 9  3:30am: GBP
draw_vertical_line(event115, color.green) // Tue May 9  4:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event116, color.blue) // Tue May 9  5:15am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event117, color.blue) // Tue May 9  7:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event118, color.blue) // Tue May 9  7:30am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event119, color.green) // Tue May 9  11:45pm: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event120, color.green) // Wed May 10  1:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event121, color.green) // Wed May 10  2:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event122, color.purple) // Wed May 10  2:45am: CHF
draw_vertical_line(event123, color.green) // Wed May 10  3:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event124, color.green) // Wed May 10  3:30am: GBP
draw_vertical_line(event125, color.green) // Wed May 10  4:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event126, color.blue) // Wed May 10  5:15am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event127, color.blue) // Wed May 10  6:45am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event128, color.blue) // Wed May 10  7:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event129, color.blue) // Wed May 10  9:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event130, color.blue) // Wed May 10  9:55am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event131, color.blue) // Wed May 10  10:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event132, color.blue) // Wed May 10  10:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event133, color.blue) // Wed May 10  11:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event134, color.orange) // Wed May 10  1:30pm: CAD
draw_vertical_line(event135, color.orange) // Wed May 10  3:00pm: CAD
draw_vertical_line(event136, color.green) // Wed May 10  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event137, color.green) // Wed May 10  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event138, color.green) // Wed May 10  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event139, color.green) // Wed May 10  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event140, color.orange) // Wed May 10  9:30pm: AUD
draw_vertical_line(event141, color.green) // Wed May 10  11:45pm: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event142, color.green) // Thu May 11  1:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event143, color.green) // Thu May 11  2:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event144, color.purple) // Thu May 11  2:45am: CHF
draw_vertical_line(event145, color.green) // Thu May 11  3:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event146, color.green) // Thu May 11  3:30am: GBP
draw_vertical_line(event147, color.green) // Thu May 11  4:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event148, color.blue) // Thu May 11  5:15am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event149, color.blue) // Thu May 11  7:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event150, color.blue) // Thu May 11  7:30am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event151, color.green) // Thu May 11  11:45pm: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event152, color.green) // Fri May 12  1:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event153, color.green) // Fri May 12  2:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event154, color.purple) // Fri May 12  2:45am: CHF
draw_vertical_line(event155, color.green) // Fri May 12  3:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event156, color.green) // Fri May 12  3:30am: GBP
draw_vertical_line(event157, color.green) // Fri May 12  4:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event158, color.blue) // Fri May 12  5:15am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event159, color.blue) // Fri May 12  6:45am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event160, color.blue) // Fri May 12  7:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event161, color.blue) // Fri May 12  9:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event162, color.blue) // Fri May 12  9:55am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event163, color.blue) // Fri May 12  10:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event164, color.blue) // Fri May 12  10:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event165, color.blue) // Fri May 12  11:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event166, color.orange) // Fri May 12  1:30pm: CAD
draw_vertical_line(event167, color.orange) // Fri May 12  3:00pm: CAD
draw_vertical_line(event168, color.green) // Fri May 12  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event169, color.green) // Fri May 12  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event170, color.green) // Fri May 12  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event171, color.green) // Fri May 12  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event172, color.orange) // Fri May 12  9:30pm: AUD
draw_vertical_line(event173, color.green) // Fri May 12  11:45pm: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event174, color.purple) // Sat May 13  All Day: CNY
draw_vertical_line(event175, color.green) // Sat May 13  1:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event176, color.green) // Sat May 13  6:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event177, color.green) // Sat May 13  11:45pm: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event178, color.purple) // Sun May 14  All Day: CNY
draw_vertical_line(event179, color.blue) // Sun May 14  6:45pm: USD
draw_vertical_line(event180, color.green) // Sun May 14  9:01pm: GBP
draw_vertical_line(event181, color.orange) // Sun May 14  11:30pm: AUD
draw_vertical_line(event182, color.green) // Mon May 15  All Day: GBP
draw_vertical_line(event183, color.green) // Mon May 15  All Day: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event184, color.green) // Mon May 15  All Day: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event185, color.green) // Mon May 15  All Day: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event186, color.blue) // Mon May 15  5:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event187, color.blue) // Mon May 15  5:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event188, color.blue) // Mon May 15  5:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event189, color.blue) // Mon May 15  7:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event190, color.blue) // Mon May 15  7:30am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event191, color.blue) // Mon May 15  8:30am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event192, color.blue) // Mon May 15  8:55am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event193, color.green) // Mon May 15  11:45pm: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event194, color.green) // Tue May 16  1:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event195, color.green) // Tue May 16  2:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event196, color.purple) // Tue May 16  2:45am: CHF
draw_vertical_line(event197, color.green) // Tue May 16  3:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event198, color.green) // Tue May 16  3:30am: GBP
draw_vertical_line(event199, color.green) // Tue May 16  4:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event200, color.blue) // Tue May 16  5:15am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event201, color.blue) // Tue May 16  7:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event202, color.blue) // Tue May 16  7:30am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event203, color.green) // Tue May 16  11:45pm: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event204, color.green) // Wed May 17  1:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event205, color.green) // Wed May 17  2:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event206, color.purple) // Wed May 17  2:45am: CHF
draw_vertical_line(event207, color.green) // Wed May 17  3:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event208, color.green) // Wed May 17  3:30am: GBP
draw_vertical_line(event209, color.green) // Wed May 17  4:00am: EUR
draw_vertical_line(event210, color.blue) // Wed May 17  5:15am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event211, color.blue) // Wed May 17  6:45am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event212, color.blue) // Wed May 17  7:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event213, color.blue) // Wed May 17  9:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event214, color.blue) // Wed May 17  9:55am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event215, color.blue) // Wed May 17  10:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event216, color.blue) // Wed May 17  10:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event217, color.blue) // Wed May 17  11:00am: USD
draw_vertical_line(event218, color.orange) // Wed May 17  1:30pm: CAD
draw_vertical_line(event219, color.orange) // Wed May 17  3:00pm: CAD
draw_vertical_line(event220, color.green) // Wed May 17  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event221, color.green) // Wed May 17  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event222, color.green) // Wed May 17  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event223, color.green) // Wed May 17  6:00pm: NZD
draw_vertical_line(event224, color.orange) // Wed May 17  9:30pm: AUD
```

using this code works just perfect, only thing thats different i believe is the length and amount of dates and times

```
study("Economic News Vertical Lines", shorttitle="Econ News", overlay=true)

// Define event times (PST, UTC-7)
event1 = timestamp("2023-05-22T00:01:00")
event2 = timestamp("2023-05-22T00:50:00")
event3 = timestamp("2023-05-22T14:00:00")
event4 = timestamp("2023-05-22T23:00:00")
event5 = timestamp("2023-05-23T00:30:00")
event6 = timestamp("2023-05-23T05:00:00")
event7 = timestamp("2023-05-23T06:00:00")
event8 = timestamp("2023-05-23T06:59:59")
event9 = timestamp("2023-05-23T07:15:00")
event10 = timestamp("2023-05-23T07:30:00")


// Function to draw vertical lines
draw_vertical_line(time_event, color) =>
    var line p = line.new(x1=time_event, y1=na, x2=time_event, y2=na, width=1, color=color, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, style=line.style_dotted)
    line.set_xy1(p, x=time_event, y=lowest(low, 500))
    line.set_xy2(p, x=time_event, y=highest(high, 500))

// Draw vertical lines for all events
draw_vertical_line(event1, color.purple) // All Day: CAD Bank Holiday
draw_vertical_line(event2, color.red) // EUR Consumer Confidence
draw_vertical_line(event3, color.green) // AUD Flash Manufacturing PMI
draw_vertical_line(event4, color.green) // AUD Flash Services PMI
draw_vertical_line(event5, color.yellow) // JPY Flash Manufacturing PMI
draw_vertical_line(event6, color.yellow) // JPY BOJ Core CPI y/y
draw_vertical_line(event7, color.blue) // GBP Public Sector Net Borrowing
draw_vertical_line(event8, color.gray) // Tentative: CHF Trade Balance
draw_vertical_line(event9, color.red) // EUR French Flash Manufacturing PMI
draw_vertical_line(event10, color.red) // EUR German Flash Manufacturing PMI
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your study call to this. The default number of lines pine draws is 50 so all of your earlier event lines get deleted

```
study("Economic News Vertical Lines", shorttitle="Econ News", overlay=true, max_lines_count = 500)
```